# How to set firebase data persistence to false in react native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I am currently creating a barber appointment system using firebase and react-native expo. I tested the application in offline mode and noticed that firebase caches the request and once the app comes online it sends them all together. So, if my user pressed the booking button twice in offline mode it will create two bookings once the app comes online.

What I have tried so far:

1. I read firebase documentation & other stack overflow questions and found out that you can set persistenceEnabled to false. However, I couldn't find a way to do that in expo & only created errors. Some suggested to use [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) but it is not supported for expo.
2. I achieved it with a workaround that simply checks if there is network connection before calling the booking function.

I am not using any firebase libraries & integrated it as mentioned in [expo-docs](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/)

I'd like to know how I can stop the requests from being cached or if there is any better solution for what I am trying to achieve.

I recently started learning these new technologies so if I made some error while asking the question or missed some point, please pardon me.

Comment: So let me ask this: You said - *So, if my user pressed the booking button twice in offline mode it will create two bookings*.  How would that be different if the user pressed the booking button twice if it was in online mode. Wouldn't that still create two bookings?

Comment: Hey @Jay. Yes, you are right. I will have to put some checks for that, but I think you have miss interpreted my question I simply asked how I could turn the value for data persistence to false in expo because I don't want the requested to be cached in expo and not about the functionality of my application.

Comment: I understood the question but wanted to mention that :-). For persistence, isn't it just a matter of getting your database and `database().setPersistenceEnabled(false);`?

Comment: I am using react-native-firebase and even `firestore().settings({persistence: false)` does not seem to turn it off for me.

Comment: HI @JeffPadgett. Thank you for giving your time to help but I already tried the commad. As I am using the firebase web sdk the persistence option doesn't work. I swithced to react native firebase which is the unofficial firebase library for rn & persistence works perfectly fine with it.